# How to add php code into my node.js libraries

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I want to include php code into my websocket (client side) with node.js

The file format example is:

- node_modules
- chat.js (server side)
- index.html (client side)
- package-lock.json

I start with **node chat.js**

so, if I change **index.html to index.php** and the chat.js to point index.php, when I try to open the site example.. "localhost:3000" it download a file "download" with my .php code. I don´t know why.
(below i will show the code..)

The other option is work all with javascript instead php.

**There is some way to work with php in node.js???**
The .html to .php reading php and js.

The code:
chat.js (server side)

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log("usuario id : %s",socket.id);
    var channel = 'channel-a';
    socket.broadcast.emit('message','El usuario '+socket.id+' se ha conectado!','System');
    socket.join(channel);
    socket.on('message',function(msj){
        io.sockets.in(channel).emit('message',msj,socket.id); //enviar a todos del canal
    });
    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log("Desconectado : %s",socket.id);
    });
    socket.on('change channel',function(newChannel){
        socket.leave(channel);
        socket.join(newChannel);
        channel = newChannel;
        socket.emit('change channel',newChannel);
    });
});
http.listen(PORT,function(){
    console.log('el servidor esta escuchando el puerto %s',PORT);
});
```

I google it/read docs node.js but I did not find anything.
Hope you can help me

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot (easily) do that.

Comment: You can put them both behind a reverse proxy like nginx & configure it to serve PHP too.

Comment: how can i do that? (hardly) @SLaks